# Ombudsman for car rentals in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection

Hypothetically, suppose person A purchased a service B from company C in the UK. If person A believes they were mis-sold the service, they could start a case with the [The Financial Ombudsman Service](https://www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk/) in case company C is a bank, with the Housing Ombudsman in case service B is rental of a property, or to [Ombudsman Services](https://www.ombudsman-services.org/sectors) in case company C is a telecom or an energy utility.

Suppose company C is a car rental company operating in the UK and based in the EU. What services would be able to mediate a complaint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no Ombudsman laid down by government regulation, and the company is not a voluntary member of an arbitration scheme, then your remedy for a complaint would be through the courts.